# Mat-Spinner with async is not finishing as I expect it to with rxjs function in Angular 12

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, angular12

I am pretty much a noob at rxjs and may be just using the wrong function completely.  Essentially I am doing a stack of .NET Core 3.1 backend and mocking a two second delay.  I am using that same service call twice to mock something similar to what I was doing on production code.  So my code even though it is wiring up is pretty similar in the concept.  I want a spinner to stop when BOTH service calls finish.  I want them both to kick off simultaneously but I don't care if they are an observable or an actual item and having the calls made simultaneously.  No matter what I have tried I keep see the spinner stays on and the context of the setting of the 'false' keeps happening.

component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { combineLatest, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Entry } from '../Models/entry.model';
import { TestService } from '../test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-Entry',
  templateUrl: './Entry.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Entry.component.scss']
})
export class EntryComponent implements OnInit {
  entry$: Observable<Entry> = this.service.getItem();
  entry2$: Observable<Entry> = this.service.getItem();
  loading$: Observable<boolean> = of(true);

  constructor(private readonly service: TestService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //my guess is this part is completely wrong for what I am trying to accomplish.
    combineLatest([this.entry$, this.entry2$]).pipe(x => this.loading$ = of(false));
  }

}
```

view:

```
<mat-spinner [hidden]="loading$ | async"></mat-spinner>
<p>
  <em>{{entry$ | async | json}}</em>
</p>
<p>
  <em>{{entry2$ | async | json}}</em>
</p>
```

Entire Project is on GitHub and public: https://github.com/djangojazz/AngularMaterial.  You just run the API in Visual Studio and then boot up the Angular client with 'npm run start'.

Comment: Why are you using the `hidden` prop for `mat-spinner`? Logically, you need to replace `[hidden]` with `*ngIf`.

Comment: Then the whole spinner goes away.  I don't really care if you can make it work with a different directive.  If I use *ngIf it goes away completely and the hidden directive shows it to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't far off with the `combineLatest` but you aren't subscribing to it.

If your `entry$` and `entry$2` observables are 1-off observables then this approach might be simpler:

```js
  entry$: Observable<any> = of('entry$').pipe(delay(500));
  entry2$: Observable<any> = of('entry2$').pipe(delay(5000));

  combined$;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.combined$ = combineLatest([this.entry$, this.entry2$]);
  }
```

```html
<div *ngIf="combined$ | async as combined; else loading">
  Data loaded
  {{combined[0]}}
  {{combined[1]}}
</div>
<ng-template #loading>
  <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</ng-template>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9suggu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

But if they constantly emit a value then you might want to subscribe to it because you'd want to show the lolading button everytime a new value emits

Also, showing the loading indicator is usually a side-effect and when side-effects are mentioned you should be using the `tap` operator.

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    combineLatest([this.entry$, this.entry2$])
      .pipe(
        tap(() => this.loading$.next(true)),
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      )
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.data1 = res[0];
        this.data2 = res[1];
        this.loading$.next(false);
      });
  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfhmxm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Sweet!  Exactly what I wanted and nice and easy to follow.  I love doing more with less.  I had no idea you can do an overload else in an *ngIf or just forgot and hadn't done it in a while.   I will keep in mind your second example but these are not constantly emitting.  In this case it would just be two service calls base on a route param and a state item that would then wire up service calls.

Comment: Yep, I wrote the 2nd one just in case :-) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use `BehaviorSubject` and `finalize` operator to properly handle your `loading$` variable. Here's code with changes.

`component.ts`:

```js
...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-Entry',
  templateUrl: './Entry.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Entry.component.scss']
})
export class EntryComponent implements OnInit {
  entry$: Observable<Entry> = this.service.getItem();
  entry2$: Observable<Entry> = this.service.getItem();
  loading$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);

  constructor(private readonly service: TestService) { 
    combineLatest([this.entry$, this.entry2$]).pipe(finalize( ()=> this.loading$.next(false) ).subscribe();
}

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

`html`:

```html
<mat-spinner *ngIf="loading$ | async"></mat-spinner>
<p>
  <em>{{entry$ | async | json}}</em>
</p>
<p>
  <em>{{entry2$ | async | json}}</em>
</p>
```

Comment: Kind of works.  It will hide the spinner when the first finishes and then the second is in process.  Deserves a plus though as it gets me pretty close.  Thanks!